# superuser.com layout bug: divs overlapping & comments not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, design

There are several problems with the layout. Right sidebar is overlapping slightly; share/edit/delete/flag links are pushed to the side; and when I click on "add comment", the add comment link disappears, but the box to add a comment with does not show.

Running firefox 21.0; I think these problems might be specific to firefox.

Screenshot here:

[image]

Problem is not specific to the superuser.com site - see also these, and notice the right sidebar is overlapping the main content:

---

**meta.superuser.com**

[image]

---

**stackoverflow.com**

[image]

Comment: sounds like older cached css/js files are being served - have you done a hard refresh?

Comment: Looks fine to me. How about starting Firefox with no extensions? There is a `Restart with Add-ons Disabled` option in the `help` menu.

Comment: Try disabling userscripts.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Bob, you're right - it was caused by greasemonkey, seems I had a script that was trying to sort the tables. I didn't realize it was being applied to the stack exchange sites. Thanks. I guess, should I delete the question? It seems silly now

Comment: @Benubird: Nothing wrong with it, feel free if you want to delete it though :)

Comment: I'm speaking from experience. Nothing like noticing some stupid self-written userscript broke the site *after* you ping SE employees :-(